# Firewall Port 1433 not opening

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection, firewall

I am using MS Server 2008 with MSSQL 2008 R2 as database server.

Each time for some work I have to login to server via Remote connection. I tried to configure the SQL Server remote connection on, followed the following steps..

1. Created Inbound and outbound rules for TCP port 1433.
2. In SQL Server configuration manager ,all is set for IP address and Pprt no properties.
3. Set the SQL Server instance for remote connections.

But still it's not working.

Also when I checked port 1433 for TCP on local computer it is shown closed.

Comment: Have you got any firewall programs running? Some sort of anti-virus all in one package, corporate firewall?

Comment: yes the server has a windows firewall running...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Probably port 1433 is disabled, so enable it using MS WIndows firewall.

or just use

```
netsh firewall set portopening protocol = TCP port = 1433 name = SQLPort mode = ENABLE scope = SUBNET profile = CURRENT
```

2. Probably MS SQL Server Browser Service is not running. So go to Services and start it.

or just execute under Run menu

> %windir%\system32\services.msc

3. Probably TCP/IP channel is disabled under SQL Server 2008/2014 Configuration Manager. SO go there and enable all TCP/IP options.

[image]

4. Just in case at the same place (SQL Server 2008/2014 Configuration Manager) make sure you have 1433 port.

[image]

5. Make sure that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. Use MS SQL Management Studio and right click on the top node which server itself.

[image]

Comment: I could access my server with firewall disabled, could not with it enabled. After running the NETSH above command still no go at first. Had to restart the firewall service, then it let me connect.

Answer (score 14):

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols, check that named pipes and tcp/ip are enabled.

If that doesn't work then it may be your firewall blocking it, try this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

This may be useful too:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

Comment: If you can't find `SQL Server Configuration Manager`, it's usually under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 7):

If named pipes and TCP/IP access are already enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager, then you need to either add a rule for **UDP** port **1434**, or a rule for **sqlbrowser.exe** so that the SSMS client can talk to the SQL Server Browser service.

I actually see people having this problem surprisingly often so I wrote up an explanation here: http://blog.dereenigne.com/microsoft-sql-server-dynamic-ports-windows-firewall-and-you/

Comment: One extra step for dynamic ports is required - make sure that the SQL Browser service is up and running, as it might been turned off.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to connect to a SQL Server Express instance as is my case right now... it doesn't use port `1433` by default. One must check IpAll => TCP Dynamic Ports in Sql Server Configuration Manager. Mine is `52848`.

After entering the correct port `52848` in DbSchema app (the one I'm trying to use), it connected successfully.

Check the following screenshot:
[image]

This is the way to go:

> The default SQL Server express installation does not enable TCP
> network protocols, so here are some steps to take to be able to
> communicate with SQL Server Express. These steps should be similar for
> MS SQL Server Express 2017, 2016, 2014, 2012, 2008, and 2005.
>
> 1. Launch the SQL Server Configuration Manager. It should be in the Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -> Configuration Tools start menu option.
> 2. Select the SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration tab. There should be a Protocols for SQLExpress option, and one of the protocols should be TCP IP.
> 3. Enable the TCP IP protocol if it is not enabled.
> 4. The default port for SQL Express may not be 1433. To find the port it is listening on, right-click on the TCP IP protocol and scroll all the way down to the IP All heading. There should be a section called TCP Dynamic Ports. This should list the port SQL Express is listening on. You can then put this value into the port field when adding the connection profile via RazorSQL.
>
> Make sure to restart SQL Express before trying to connect.

Text reproduced from:
https://razorsql.com/docs/support_sqlserver_express.html

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple NICs in my server. When I went to SQL Server Network Configuration -> TCP/IP and right clicked for properties there was a list of the NICs and at the bottom was the open port for my SQLEXPRESS. It was not 1433..... I do not know if there is a default but mine was in the 49,000 s.