# IIS Hosting and SQL Server 2008 R2 not available online

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, iis-7.5, host

I have succeeded in hosting my applications locally but when i try to view it through a network outside it fails.

Same goes for my SQL Server, I am able to connect locally.

I have tried to open my port but it keeps failing, Is the port the cause of the problem?
Server Manager is also not found in my IIS

PS. I am using windows 8

Please help, it would benefit my school project alot

Comment: Probably a firewall issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open port 1433 for access to SQL Server:

[Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304249/firewall-port-1433-not-opening).

You will also need to enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: I followed some of the instructions in the link enabling port 1433, sqlserv, and the command to open the port. Have not tried to connect remotely but when i open up my Sql Server Configuration Manager, my SQL Server Services gives The remote procedure call failed. [0x800706be]. Do i have to reinstall Sql Server?

Comment: Hi, installed the Sql service pack, i tested my port again, this time 1433 is opened thanks!
Is there any similar guides to opening port for IIS?

Comment: Port 80 is open by default - what error message are you getting?