# Windows 2008 Server - cannot open port 1433 for external access

Tags: sql-server

I have a Windows 2008 Server with SQL 2012 Express installed and running on it.

although I have shut down the local Windows Firewall and even followed the suggestions on this article:

[Firewall Port 1433 not opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304249/firewall-port-1433-not-opening)

I cannot seem to be able to access this service from outside the server, thus trying:

```
telnet x.x.x.x 1433
```

(where "x.x.x.x" being the external public IP address of the server)

When running this telnet command locally on the server, everything seems to be just fine.

What am I missing here??

Comment: For that matter, I should mention that other standard ports (21, 80...) are working just fine for external access.

Answer (score 0):

After searching relentlessly, I have finally found the answer for this issue:

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/configuring-ms-sql-server-for-remote-access

All I needed to do is to define port 1433 on the SQL Server Configuration tool, as described in the article above.

Hope this can help others out there like me...

Happy Coding!