# Connecting to SQLServer with GORM

Tags: sql-server, go, go-gorm

I am using the statement below to try and open a connection to the latest download of SQLServer Express.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mssql"
    "log"
)

        db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", "sqlserver://tony:Password6!@localhost:1433?database=go_user")
```

The statement results in an error:

> 2019/09/30 10:29:16 Unable to open tcp connection with host
>   'localhost:1433': dial tcp [::1]:1433: connectex: No connection could
>   be made because the target machine actively refused it. panic: Unable
>   to open tcp connection with host 'localhost:1433': dial tcp
>   [::1]:1433: connectex: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.

Is anyone successfully connecting to SQLServer Express with GORM on Golang?

Comment: That's not a valid SQL Server Express string. SQL Server Express installs only named instances. Use `localhost\\SQLEXPRESS` instead of `localhost`

Comment: I have tried various permutations of that, but gorm does not like when you insert "\\" into the connection string.  The result is:  invalid character "\\" in host name.

Comment: I realize that doesn't look like a SQL Server connect string, this is GORM's interpretation of a SQL Server connect string.  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TCP port 1433 is the default port for `SQL Server`. This port is also the official Internet Assigned Number Authority (IANA) socket number for SQL Server. Client systems use TCP 1433 to connect to the database engine; SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) uses the port to manage SQL Server instances across the network. You can reconfigure `SQL Server` to listen on a different port, but 1433 is by far the most common implementation.

However, if you still want to open it, follow the below steps:

**Step 1**

Probably TCP/IP channel is disabled under `SQL Server Configuration Manager`. SO go there and enable all TCP/IP options.

[image]

**Step 2**

Just in case at the same place `SQL Server Configuration Manager` make sure you have 1433 port.

[image]

**Step 3**

Make sure that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. Use MS SQL Management Studio and right click on the top node which server itself.

[image]

Credit from the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304249/firewall-port-1433-not-opening/13306515).

Comment: This would apply only if the connection string pointed to the correct named database. It doesn't

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - totally agree and thanks for mentioning. Just wanted to expose how to configure and open the port in case of a pointed connection string.

Comment: There's a highly upvoted question that shows how to troubleshoot networking issues. If that were the case here the question would be closed as a duplicate already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - there is. A solution I've posted the link to.

Comment: This is a partial answer.  The final thing I did to make it work correctly was to go to SQL Server Configuration Manager -- > SQL Server Network Configuration -- > TCP/IP (double click) -- > IP Addresses -- > Scroll all the way down to IPALL -- > Set port to 1433